# Can ArcGIS Server WMS display a graphicslayer?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

I have tried to display a graphics layer with the WMS functionality of ArcGIS Server, but I cannot see the graphics in the image of the getmap response.

I have done is manually by publishing a service with a graphics on an annotation layer, associated this annotation layer with a specific feature layer, and published it, but the graphics is not appearing, only the features.

And I have done it programmatically by creating a graphicslayer and assign it to a layer, and its the same, graphics are not appearing on the map image returned by WMS.

When I do a REST call to the service I can see the graphics in both cases.

Are graphics not supported with WMS or am I doing something wrong?

I am using ArcGIS Server 9.3.1, Java version.

Nicole

Comment: When you mention REST call, do you mean to the specific WMS endpoint or just view the map service via Javascript viewer?

Comment: I mean the specific WMS endpoint. when I am using the Javascript viewer which I am assuming is using the REST endpoint I can see the graphics

Answer (score 1):

I have [not found any clear evidence](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=27825) that you cannot view graphics on an annotation layer.
If you just add basic annotation to that layer, does that appear in the WMS?

Comment: i was looking at the same page you are mentioning, and there is nothing related to my problem. To test it, I have created a mxd document with just one feature on a layer. Then I have used the drawing tool and have written some text, and published it. the text is visible via the REST endpoint, but not via the WMS endpoint. I have drawn the text on an annotation group assigned to the feature layer.

Comment: Afterwards I have tried the same by drawing on the default annotation group which is not assigned to a layer and it does not appear either.